# Java - as boundaries depend on the window sizes

Tags: java, jfreechart

as boundaries which are selected with red points, from the window sizes depend?

For example, their coordinates with window size 640x480 are (59, 67) and (631, 475).

1. (59, 67) and (696, 545) when 712x579
2. (59, 96) and (809, 682) when 825x687
3. (59, 96) and (990, 748) when 1006x753

how to find regularity of dependence of coordinates from the window size?

[image: Boundaries of JFreeChart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart) the [ChartPanel](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) class has the [getScreenDataArea()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#getScreenDataArea%28%29) method to give you this info.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it gets coordinates of this red points:

```
Rectangle2D plotArea = chartPanel.getScreenDataArea();
double maxx = plotArea.getMaxX();
double minx = plotArea.getMinX();
double miny = height - plotArea.getMaxY();
double maxy = height - plotArea.getMinY();
```